# Visual Studio Code Debug asp net core web app

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, debugging, visual-studio-code

I have a full Asp net core React Web Application which I want to try debugging on vs code to use the amazing extension it offers, the problem is the breakpoints only work on .cs files (tried on startup.cs and it works fine) and not on the javascript files...

Does anyone know if it is possible to debug such a solution with vs code or I have to stick with Visual Studio :(?

Thanks

Comment: Based on this article from Microsoft the debug in VS code is not working, only in Visual Studio. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/debug-nodejs?view=vs-2022). U can see it on the line - Applies to

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio:

You can add `debugger` to the JavaScript file as a breakpoint for debugging.When you call this file, it will automatically jump to the debugger location for debugging，like this:

JavaScript:

```
function clickMe() {
    debugger;
    alert('Hello World');
}
```

View:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src=~/mylib.js></script>
<button onclick = "clickMe()">click</button>
```

Test Result:

[image]

For more details please refer to [this link](https://learningprogramming.net/net/asp-net-core-mvc-5/use-images-css-and-javascript-in-asp-net-core-mvc-5/).

In VS Code:

You can add `debugger` to the JavaScript file, and use the browser's developer tools for breakpoint debugging.
For more details please refer to [this link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging).

Hope this can help you.